# JEA Invoke Command Issue

Tags: powershell

I have been working on implementing **JEA** into my environment to allow for our Jenkins System to not have local admin controls on all of our servers.

I have been able to create the JEA files, and specified commands that the user account can run. 
The problem i am running into is that i am needing to pass a variable value from my Jenkins server to a remote server. So far i am not able to perform this.

Here is the code i am using with Powershell:

```
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "webaoneratebook" -ConfigurationName JEA-A1
$user = "USER"
$File = "C:\users\svc.jenkins.prd\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\FILE.txt"
$myCredentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user ,(Get-Content $file| ConvertTo-SecureString)
$pass = $MyCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password
Start-sleep -s 3
Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock {AnalyzeRatebook} -ArgumentList $pass
Get-PSSession| Remove-PSSession
```

No matter what i have tried, i cannot seem to get the password to pass over.
In the *JEA PSRC* file, i have set the following remote variables:

```
VariableDefinitions =   @{ Name = 'log'; Value = 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Jenkinstemp\A1Log.log'}, 
                    @{ Name = 'binpath'; Value = 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\AscendantOne\bin' },
                    @{ Name = 'user'; Value = 'USER' },
                    @{ Name = 'pass2'; Value = 'TEMP' },
                    @{ Name = 'manifest'; Value = 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Jenkinstemp\manifest.xml' }
```

In the *JEA PSRC* file, i have made my function like this:

```
    FunctionDefinitions = @{
    'Name' = 'AnalyzeRatebook'
    'ScriptBlock' = {
                & $binpath\AOImportCmd.exe -u $user -p $pass -o $log -a $manifest
        }
}
```

And made sure it is in Visible Functions as well.

```
VisibleFunctions = 'AnalyzeRatebook','TestRatebook',@{ Name = 'AnalyzeRatebook'; Parameters = @{ Name = 'ArgumentList'}}
```

If i do a `Write-Host "& $binpath\AOImportCmd.exe -u $user -p $pass -o $log -a $manifest"`, I get back everything except the password.

So can anyone give some advice on how to get the local variable to translate over to a remote system when using JEA?

Comment: The remotely executed script block you're passing `$pass` to via `-ArgumentList $pass` sees it as `$Args[0]`, given that the script block has no `param(...)` block. Such a script block knows nothing about the caller's variables per se.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
So as this is controlled by the JEA Role file, would the param go in therre, or as part of the icm?

And I have tried adding the param for this prior with not effect.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with JEA, but try using `$Args[0]` instead of `$pass` in the script block assigned to the `'ScriptBlock'` entry in your PSRC file.

Comment: Thank you for the help.
I have confined this to be an issue with the JEA in particular. 

Once i eliminated that, everything worked correctly. The JEA is just not allowing me to pass local variables across despite the params or argument list.

Comment: Once i find a working solution, i will provide it here.

Comment: Re posting a solution: please do. Remoting never allows you to access the caller's local variables directly; if you pass their values as arguments, you can either use the `$Args` array, or you can add a `param()` block to your script block (immediately after the opening `{`)  to _name_ the arguments and thus create local variables; e.g., `param([string] $pass)`.

Comment: After bashing my head against the wall for multiple hours today, my coworker pointed out a flaw in how i had parameters set in the JEA PSRC file. I initially had then set as :
`Param($user),($pass),($log),($manifest)`

i changed that to:
`Param($user,$pass,$log,$manifest)`

Comment: Then i changed my ICM from the remote system. 

`Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock {Param($user,$pass,$log,$manifest) AnalyzeRatebook -u"$user" -p"$pass" -o"$log" $manifest} -ArgumentList $user,$pass,$log,$manifest`

Comment: The other change i made was to set `JEA PSSC` to run in full language mode instead of no-language mode.

`LanguageMode = 'FullLanguage'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## More Secure Resolution:

I worked a bit more and found a better answer that preserves the `NoLanguage` Mode of `JEA`. This is useful since `ConstrainedLanguage` Mode and `FullLanguage` Mode give too much power for modification even in `JEA` limited accounts.

In the end, i had to add two additional cmdlets to the `VisibleCmdlets` listing.
`Get-Variable` and `Set-Variable`.

Once i added these, I was able to set the system back to `NoLanguage` mode, and then pass my local variables to the remote host via the `ICM` command below:

`Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock {AnalyzeRatebook -u"$Using:user" -p"$Using:pass" -o"$Using:log" $Using:manifest}`

## Alternative Resolution

The problem was due to Three (edit: math is hard) reasons:
 1. No-Language Mode was configured. This is modified in the PSSC file. 
 2. User error with how i defined Param in the PSRC file.
 3. ICM needed to be changed in how it reached out.

## Item 1:

To resolve, i went into the `JEA-A1.PSSC` file on the remote system, then (in this case, there was never a language mode defined) added a new line to the file called LanguageMode.
`LanguageMode = 'FullLanguage'`

## Item 2

Then i updated the Custom Function that i wrote in the `JEA-A1.PSRC`file with the correct syntax.

## Original:

```
# Functions to define when applied to a session 
FunctionDefinitions = @{
    'Name' = 'AnalyzeRatebook'
    'ScriptBlock' = {
    Param($user),($pass),($log),($manifest)
            & $binpath\AOImportCmd.exe "-a" $user $pass $log $manifest
            $LASTEXITCODE

        }
}
```

## Corrected:

```
# Functions to define when applied to a session 
FunctionDefinitions = @{
    'Name' = 'AnalyzeRatebook'
    'ScriptBlock' = {
    Param($user,$pass,$log,$manifest)
            & $binpath\AOImportCmd.exe "-a" $user $pass $log $manifest
            $LASTEXITCODE

    }
}
```

## Item 3:

Finally the `Invoke-Command` call needed to be updated to accurately read and parse the variables. In my case, I could not set them to a single string as the system was expecting a pause in between the values to signify what they were.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock {Param($user,$pass,$log,$manifest) AnalyzeRatebook -u"$user" -p"$pass" -o"$log" $manifest} -ArgumentList $user,$pass,$log,$manifest
```

Now this is working and passing the values correctly.

Comment: One item. I found that when i modified the `pssc` file, I needed to unregister and then register the `JEA` configuration.